# Input checking for php. Best library/framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter php MVC framework to develop a web application.  I have an input textarea that I would like to validate the input on.  Basically it is similar to the textarea that I am typing in right now for stackoverflow, minus most (maybe all) of the formatting features that it has.  Is there a simple built in way of doing this in codeigniter? If not, what would be the best way to approach this?  Basically I want the input filtered and formatted properly both before writing to the database and also for retrieving the text for display on the page.  I assume I would need all the basic regex checks and character escaping (like double quotes etc.) as well as sql injection protection.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the same [SO editor](http://wmd-editor.com/) or [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) or a [regular WYSIWYG](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) for user's input.

Regarding security or sql injection, look at [html purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison). you have a nice [comparative](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison) here that can help you to see which one is the best for you... remember that more rules to check usually means more overhead

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do sounds more like sanitizing your input, not validating.  If you use CodeIgniter's [ActiveRecord functions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html), you will be protected from SQL injections.  For everything else, you'll have to write on your own code, probably in a function in your model before you send it to the database.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "everything else".  I just read the page you linked to and it seems like it handles escaping values automatically.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter has its own Form Validation library. See [link text](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html).

It "... provides a comprehensive form validation and data prepping class that helps minimize the amount of code you'll write."

Of course, it is server-side validation.  You might want to look at jQuery's Validation plugin for your client-side validations.  See [link text](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).